# How to help your R8 perform at its highest level

Tags: android, android-studio, optimization, proguard, android-r8

As far as I know, this is the basic optimization for the application when building the release version with r8 enabledin the following way https://i.stack.imgur.com/BbTHD.png Currently, I am not using any rules in proguard-rules.pro.
I use r8 for my app, it works fine, however when decompiling some other apps, I found their r8 works better than what I saw with my app, I think there might be some command lines inside the proguard file can do this. How to make R8 as optimal as possible in the project?

Comment: "when decompiling some other apps, I found their r8 works better" how do you know their use R8/Proguard? There are dozen of other (commercial) Android app obfuscators available.